# Can't statically link MFC + MSVC++ runtimes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mfc

I've got a C++ project in visual studio 2013 that I need to build with the MFC and MSVC++ runtime libraries linked statically.

Currently, it compiles successfully when they are linked dynamically / shared.

When I change these two options:

1. Use of MFC: Use MFC in a Shared DLL -> Use MFC in a Static Library
2. Runtime library: Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) -> Multi-threaded (/MT)

I get a slew of linker errors, telling me that common library functions cannot be resolved, such as free, malloc, ...

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
```

How can I get my project to link to the runtimes statically?

Comment: Why is linking dynamically not good enough?

Comment: Because I must deliver this library I am building as part of a contract and that is a requirement. It is government so there is no other way

Comment: And why can't you deliver it as a shared library (dll or so) sitting next to your executable? It seems silly to require that everything be compiled into a single static executable/library.

Comment: I assume you *did* do a full rebuild after changing the settings. It's hard to guess the problem without seeing (more of) the project files.